# Restart android service once it is stopped when application closed through task manager

Tags: android

I was using a service which will update my application whenever new update is available in server. So my service run and it always check with server for version update and if i get new version update it will install.

My issues whenever i closed my application form `taskmanager` my service is getting killed. I used `START_STICKY` in `onstartcommand()` also even though it is not working. Is their is any chance to restart my service once it is `stopped by taskmanager`.

Comment: You do not need a continuously-running service for this. Use `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` to check for an update occasionally.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to periodically wake up your application (i.e. activity or a service). This way you won't need to run service in the background all the time.

Just set AlarmManager to wake your app/service every day/week, check for an update, and then close the service. Check out [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) on how to use AlarmManager.

This approach will be better than running your own service, because it'd use no memory or battery power. Your users will thank you for that!

If your application is designed to run on API level 21 or newer (which means Android 5.0 Lollipop), you can also take advantage of [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html). It might be useful, i.e. it could schedule update check to run when device is plugged in, to further save power.

Answer (score 0):

You can owerride this method [onTaskRemoved](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) to start service again via [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Notice that the onStartCommand() method must return an integer. The integer is a value that describes how the system should continue the service in the event that the system kills it (as discussed above, the default implementation for IntentService handles this for you, though you are able to modify it). The return value from onStartCommand() must be one of the following constants:
>
> [**START_NOT_STICKY**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY)
>
> If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, do not recreate the service, unless there are pending intents to deliver. This is the safest option to avoid running your service when not necessary and when your application can simply restart any unfinished jobs.
>
> [**START_STICKY**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)
>   If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, recreate the service and call onStartCommand(), but do not redeliver the last intent. Instead, the system calls onStartCommand() with a null intent, unless there were pending intents to start the service, in which case, those intents are delivered. This is suitable for media players (or similar services) that are not executing commands, but running indefinitely and waiting for a job.
>
> [**START_REDELIVER_INTENT**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT)
>
> If the system kills the service after onStartCommand() returns, recreate the service and call onStartCommand() with the last intent that was delivered to the service. Any pending intents are delivered in turn. This is suitable for services that are actively performing a job that should be immediately resumed, such as downloading a file.

Have you tried to return the `onStartCommand()` with `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` ?